# Hide fingerprint screen when coming back from Home screen

Tags: flutter

i have app with two screens,one fingerprint screen and another home screen.once
fingerprint is authenticated i will get routed to home screen(using **navigator.push()**),but if I click back button in phone now it is getting routed to fingerprint screen again.Now how to close the app instead of routing back to finger print screen?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Navigator.pushReplacement`. It will replace the current topmost widget on the stack with the new one instead of simply pushing it on top.

Example usage -

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
```

More documentation about this method can be found [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html).

Answer (score 0):

put your homepage scaffold inside WillPopScope as a child

```
WillPopScope( 
    child: Scaffold(...), 
    onWillPop: () async {
                  return false;
    },
),
```